# reading object from a different entity group within a transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

What im trying to do:

```
public void updatePremiumFeatureData(Key userKey, OrderItemsDTO orderItemsDTO) throws Exception {
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Transaction txn = pm.currentTransaction();

        try {
            txn.begin();

            UserDTO userData = pm.getObjectById(UserDTO.class, userKey);
            PremiumFeatureDataDTO premiumFeatureData = userData.getPremiumFeatureData();

            for (OrderItemDTO orderItemDTO : orderItemsDTO.getItems()) {
                ProductDTO productDTO = pm.getObjectById(ProductDTO.class, orderItemDTO.getProductKey());

                if (productDTO.getType() == ProductType.PREMIUM_TEMPLATES) {
                    int months = getMonthsToIncrement(orderItemDTO, productDTO);

                    premiumFeatureData.incrementPremiumTemplateExpiryDateBy(months);
                }
                ...
            }

            txn.commit();

            cacheService.removeUser(userKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GAELogger.logError(LOG, e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (txn.isActive()) {
                txn.rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }
    }
```

and in production on save it says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG
```

for:

```
ProductDTO productDTO = pm.getObjectById(ProductDTO.class, orderItemDTO.getProductKey());
```

I know i cannot write multiple entity groups in a transaction (unless i turn on cross-group transaction, which i do not want to)

i have also tried class ProductDAO:

```
public ProductDTO getProductByKey(Key productKey) throws Exception {
        ProductDTO productDTO = null;

        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

        try {
            productDTO = pm.getObjectById(ProductDTO.class, productKey);
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GAELogger.logError(LOG, e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }

        return productDTO;
    }
```

and then:

```
ProductDTO productDTO = new ProductDAO().getProductByKey(key);
```

instead of:

```
ProductDTO productDTO = pm.getObjectById(ProductDTO.class, orderItemDTO.getProductKey());
```

Is there a work around just for the read bit? i.e. i want to read an entity group in a transaction with no intention to write to it. Is this possible?

work around:

i had to load productDTOs into a map and then use data in map in transaction. something like:

```
Map<Key, ProductDTO> map = new HashMap<Key, ProductDTO>();
for (OrderItemDTO orderItemDTO : orderItemsDTO.getItems()) {
    ProductDTO productDTO = pm.getObjectById(ProductDTO.class, orderItemDTO.getProductKey());
    map.put(productDTO.getKey(), productDTO);
}
```

Comment: Have separate pm instance for each class

Comment: <property name="datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName" value="true"/> means that its a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

```
datanucleus.singletonPMFForName

Description Whether to only allow a singleton PMF for a particular name 
(the name can be either the name of the PMF in jdoconfig.xml, or the name of the 
persistence-unit). If a subsequent request is made for a PMF with a name that 
already exists then a warning will be logged and the original PMF returned.
```

As per DataNucleus documentation only the factory class is made singleton. So what we want is to use different instance of `PersistenceManager` for different entities.

Comment: i have tried that. did new ProductDAO().getProductByKey(Key productKey) which does a PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager(); again. that also fails with same error.